# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' for login api

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the users data from the database and sign in to the app using state management
whenever I'm pressing the login button this error occurs although I'm add the toString() to the id
what can I do to resolve this problem

//this is the post function

```
postRequest(String url, Map data)async{
    try{
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data);
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var responsebody = jsonDecode (response.body);
        return responsebody ;

      }else{
        print("Error ${response.body}");
      }
    }catch(e){
      print("Error catch $e");

    }

  }
```

this is the login response

```
if(response['status'] == "success"){
        sharedpref.setString('id', response['data']['id'].toString());
        sharedpref.setString('name', response['data']['name']);
       sharedpref.setString('password', response['data']['password']);
        if(response['data']['name'] == "admin"){

          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("adminpage", (route) => false);

        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("home", (route) => false);
        }


      }
    }
```